# RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY() return -1

Tags: c#, sql-server

This has been troubling for a couple of days and can't solve it.

When I execute a query for inserting a record into the database, I am using `RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and it returns a value of -1.

[image: RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns -1]

This is the code that calls the method

```
NewFolder newFolder = new NewFolder(myFilePath,  myFolderDesc);

tempInt = 0;
tempInt = balconette.AddNewFolder(newFolder);

MessageBox.Show("" + tempInt);
```

The method that it is called

```
private String connString = @"Data Source=ERNIE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RLT;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
private int tempValue;

public int AddNewFolder(NewFolder newFolder)
{
    tempValue = 0;

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("usp_FileLocation_Insert", sqlCon);
        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@FileLocPath", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = newFolder.StrFolderPath;
        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@FileLocDesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = newFolder.StrFolderDesc;

        sqlCon.Open();
        tempValue = sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCon.Close();
    }

    return tempValue;
}
```

The stored procedure is as follows

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_FileLocation_Insert]
    @FileLocPath NVARCHAR(150),
    @FileLocDesc NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO FileLocation(FileLocationPath, FilelocationDesc)
    VALUES (@FileLocPath, @FileLocDesc)

    RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

The results look like this

[image: Insert Results]

Could anybody throw some light on to a possible solution, but as well could I find why it has happened?

Comment: Scope_identity() returns the value of the Identity column in the table, if it has one. Does it have one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to ExecuteScalar rather than ExecuteNonQuery.